# The Mac terminal doesn't output if the number of iterations is too high

Tags: macos, terminal, atom-editor

The code works fine if I ask it to iterate like 3 times but that is the max, after that the terminal doesn't output anything and just saves the session.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
  int i = 0 ;
  int n;
  int run;
  double d;
  double seed;
  double x;
  double y;
  double numx[run];
  double numy[run];
  double points[run];
  double sum;
  printf("Enter the seed for the random number generator: ");
  scanf("%lf", &seed);
  srand(seed);
  printf("Enter the number of iterations to run: ");
  scanf("%d", &run );
  for (i = 0; i < run; i++) {
    x = (double)rand()/RAND_MAX*2.0-1.0;
    printf(" x:%lf ", x*x);
    numx[i] = x*x;
  }
  printf("\n");
  i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < run; i++) {
    y = (double)rand()/RAND_MAX*2.0-1.0;
    printf(" y:%lf ", y*y);
    numy[i] = y*y;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < run; i++){
    d = pow(numx[i]+ numy[i], 0.5);
    if (d <= 1.0){
      n += 1;
    }
  }
  printf("\n");
  printf("Number of points in circle: %d\n", n);

    return 0;
}
```

This is what happens at 3 iterations:

```
Last login: Wed Oct 20 16:49:13 on ttys000
dhruvbishnoi@campus-031-248 ~ % /var/folders/yw/dq69cddx0ln9pwxkhnjpw_n40000gn/T/pi ; exit;
Enter the seed for the random number generator: 41      
Enter the number of iterations to run: 3
 x:0.998717  x:0.045754  x:0.920902 
 y:0.371260  y:0.471850  y:0.911363 
Number of points in circle: 1
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

This is what happens at 4 iterations:

```
Last login: Wed Oct 20 16:49:27 on ttys000
dhruvbishnoi@campus-031-248 ~ % /var/folders/yw/dq69cddx0ln9pwxkhnjpw_n40000gn/T/pi ; exit;
Enter the seed for the random number generator: 41
Enter the number of iterations to run: 4
 x:0.998717  x:0.045754  x:0.920902  x:0.371260 
zsh: segmentation fault  /var/folders/yw/dq69cddx0ln9pwxkhnjpw_n40000gn/T/pi
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

This is what happens when I tell it to iterate 5 or more times:

```
Last login: Wed Oct 20 16:50:20 on ttys000
dhruvbishnoi@campus-031-248 ~ % /var/folders/yw/dq69cddx0ln9pwxkhnjpw_n40000gn/T/pi ; exit;
Enter the seed for the random number generator: 41
Enter the number of iterations to run: 5
zsh: segmentation fault  /var/folders/yw/dq69cddx0ln9pwxkhnjpw_n40000gn/T/pi
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

The problem might be caused due to my terminal(Mac) since something similar has been happening with my other projects but only recently.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a number of arrays based on the value in the variable `run` but it hasn't been assigned a value when you do that.  At some point, that causes you to write to a bad address.  In your case, it seems that point is 4 steps into the uninitialized area.

A quick fix would be to create your arrays at a constant size and then make sure the entered value for `run` is less than the constant.

Comment: Thanks :)  The code seems to be working now. But can you tell me what is a bad address and why it gets written there so that I can solve the problem myself in the future instead of relying on other people.                                                                       P.S This problem also occurs in my other projects even though they don't use arrays, do you know could be causing that?

Comment: Here's a link that goes into an explanation of memory usage: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-static-and-dynamic-memory-allocation-in-c/.  If your other projects don't use arrays, you likely have a somewhat different problem there.